# Seleccionar a partir de un mes anterior para adelante usando bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Buenas estoy trabajando con Bootraps DatePicker , he conseguido que se seleccione meses , como podria hacer para que los meses pasados se deshabiliten  exepto un mes anterior al mes actual ?osea que se seleccione apartir del mes anterior

```
$('#mescierre').datepicker({
                format: "mm-yyyy",
                startView: "months", 
                minViewMode: "months",
                autoclose: true,locale:'es', language: 'es'
       });
```

> https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Puedes compartir tu codigo de meses, trato con tu codigo pero me salen dias y meses y años

Answer (score 0):

Está en la documentación: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#startdate

Se utiliza: **startDate** de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#mescierre').datepicker({
            format: "mm-yyyy",
            startDate: "01/01/2017",
            startView: "months", 
            minViewMode: "months",
            autoclose: true,locale:'es', language: 'es'
   });
```

**Edición**

Ahora para jugar con las fechas:

```
var ahora = new Date();
var d = ahora.getDate();
var m = ahora.getMonth() +1; //Considerando que Enero = 0 (donde inicia)
var y = ahora.getFullYear();
console.log( d+" "+m+" "+y); 21 6 2017
```

Como vas a necesitar a partir del mes anterior,

```
var ahora = new Date();
var primerDiaDelAnteriorMes = new Date(ahora.getFullYear(), ahora.getMonth() - 1, 1);
console.log(primerDiaDelAnteriorMes); //Date 2017-05-01T07:00:00.000Z
//Ahora para convertirlo en algo que sea compatible con el parámetro esperado:
var fechaCorta = (primerDiaDelAnteriorMes.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + primerDiaDelAnteriorMes.getDate() + '/' +  primerDiaDelAnteriorMes.getFullYear();
console.log(fechaCorta); // Nos da como resultado: 5/1/2017
```

Ahora con lo antes mencionado, vamos terminando de armar el cubo de rubik :D

```
$('#mescierre').datepicker({
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        startDate: "'"+fechaCorta+"'",
        startView: "months", 
        minViewMode: "months",
        autoclose: true,locale:'es', language: 'es'
});
```

Comment: lo pruebo como indica pero solo desabilita los pasados  como seria para que permita seleccionar apartir del mes anterior .

Comment: jugando con las fechas, acabo de editar la respuesta :D